# C++ assigning function pointed by function pointer to another function pointer

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a C++ function pointer in a class ClassA:

```
void (ClassA::*funcPntr1)(void);
```

pointing to function:

```
void func();
```

by using assignment:

```
functPntr1 = &ClassA::func;
```

Now, i have another function pointer:

```
void (ClassA::*funcPntr2)(void);
```

I want funcPntr2 to point to the the function pointed by the funcPntr1.
How do i do that?

I have tried this:

```
funcPntr2 = &(this->*funcPntr); //normally, i invoke the function pointer by (this->*funcPntr)()
```

But is wrong. I have tried many logical combinations, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `funcPntr2 = funcPntr;`?

Comment: But doesn't that just copy the pointer and not the function pointed to by the pointer?

Comment: If you want funcPntr2 to refer to the referent of funcPntr, then you want funcPtr2 to equal funcPntr. So funcPtr2 = funcPntr;

Comment: Wait, hang on, that does copy the pointer. It sounds like that's what you want. Do you want the function itself to also be copied? That will take a bit more than one line of code.

Comment: If its copying the pointer, then what happens when i change the function pointed by funcPntr1? Doesn't that change funcPntr2 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With assignment:

```
funcPntr2 = funcPntr;
```

Comment: Doesn't that just copy the pointer and not the function pointed to by the pointer?

Comment: @Alterecho: Functions are not objects, and neither are member functions. There is no notion of "copying a function".

Comment: What happens when i change the function pointed by funcPntr after the assignment?

Comment: @Alterecho Then the old contents remain, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Alterecho: You cannot "change a function". The function is fixed once you've defined it in your source code.

Comment: Suppose after assigning `funcPntr2 = funcPntr1;` i change the funcPntr1 to point to some other function and then invoke funcPntr2, which function gets invoked?

Comment: Function pointers work just like normal pointers. They point to whatever they point to. It doesn't matter whether you change the variables of any other pointers. `funcPntr2` will just keep pointing to that same function.

Comment: While self-modifying code is probably not what @Alterecho meant with "What happens when i change the **function** pointed..." It sure did pique my interest! Also once (if ever) c++ gets static-reflection powerful enough, there might be situations where comptime pointers may become stale when the literal code of the functions is mutated (comptime too of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the pointer which is currently assigned to it, it is a mere assignment, as others said (`funcPntr2 = funcPntr`).

If you want this assignment to persist, i. e. if you want that `funcPntr2` always points to where `funcPntr` points to, even if the latter one changes, there is no way unless you change the definition.

You'd have to

- have a `void (ClassA::**funcPntr2)(void);`
- assign `funcPntr2 = &funcPntr` and
- call `(*funcPntr)()`.

As you talk about C++, I am not so familiar with; maybe you can do something with references.

Comment: That still depends on the first funcPntr. I am trying to make funcPntr2 independent funcPntr1 after the assignment. There is no way to do it then?